# string from array

Tags: bash, string, array

I have an array named `nmser` in a bash script and I would like to make a string from it and store it in the variable `flsel`.

```
flsel=echo "${nmser[*]}"
```

Answer (score 9):

If you drop the `echo` you’ll get the contents of the array, separated by spaces (strictly speaking, the first character of the `IFS` variable, which is space by default¹), in `flsel`:

```
flsel="${nmser[*]}"
```

---

<sup>¹ With `IFS` set to the empty string, array elements will be joined together without separator.</sup>

Comment: +1. and if they want it without spaces, they can use `printf '%s'`.  e.g. `flsel=$(printf '%s' "${nmser[@]}")`

Comment: What is the difference between `${nmser[@]}` and `${nmser[*]}` ?

Comment: @Pietru inside double quotes, `[@]` expands to separate words (in shell terminology), which isn’t what you want here. See [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) for details.

Comment: Would I then have two options?  `flsel=${nmser[@]}` and `flsel="${nmser[*]}"`.

Comment: @Pietru No. `flsel=${nmser[@]}` is assigning a list to a single string, something that you semantically don't want to do (`bash` lets you do it, but that's just hiding an error of thought), while `"${nmser[*]}"` by definition is a string and what you should be using here.

Comment: @cas: Or ```printf -v flsel '%s' "${nmser[@]}"``` if we want to avoid a subshell

Comment: @spuck yes, that's much better.   `printf -v` only works in bash and zsh, though.  Not in ash, dash, or ksh.

Comment: To check visually the difference betwen @ or * as index in arrays between double quotes use: `arr=( a b c ) ;  single=( "${arr[*]}" ) ; multi=( "${arr[@]}" ) ; declare -p arr single multi `  so you can see the `[@]` separates the values of the original array 'arr' for the command where it is used, and they are assigned individually to elements of result array 'multi', just reconstructing 'arr'. Instead, `[*]` expands to a single value and the array 'single' gets only one element.